# How to add spaces to HTML clipboard data so that WinWord inserts them on pasting?

Tags: html, ms-word, clipboard, clipboarddata

In my application you can copy data to the clipboard. The data is copied to the clipboard in HTML format so that format information is preserved when pasting to other applications that can handle HTML data from the clipboard (e.g. WinWord).

**Example (4 words, the last 2 bold):**

```
<span>This is </span><b>bold text</b>
```

*Result:* The text is correctly pasted in WinWord and the format (bold) is preserved.

**Example (5 spaces):**

```
<span>     </span>
```

*Result:* Nothing is pasted in WinWord.

Question: How can I achieve that WinWord preserves the spaces in the second example?

I tried encoding them as `&nbsp;` but then WinWord shows them as a circle when paragraph marks are activated. And that looks kind of ugly.

Comment: My instinct would be that this is correct behaviour -- why would you want to copy an empty element (with not even any formatting)?  I think most applications would resist pasting nothing.  If you really must, you need to intercept the Copy operation and insert some text if the element is empty, before transfer to the clipboard - this is possible but not easy.

Comment: @TonyDuffill: My application is a text editor that already intercepts the Clipboard Copy-Operation and builds the HTML for the clipboard on its own. You can for instance copy the text `a     b     c    d` (<- there are 5 spaces between the letters) from the application to the clipboard. However when pasted into Word it is added as `a b c d` (so all spaces are reduced to a single one). You are right that those spaces are omitted using the `<span>`-tag in the browsers too as they are not considered as relevant content. My question is more like: How can you create HTML that forces the spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the CSS value `white-space:pre` to the `<span>` tags.

While `white-space:pre-wrap` seems to be the correct value, it is ignored by WinWord.

**UPDATE:**

I also analysed how WinWord creates its clipboard data. The HTML of several spaces looks like this:

```
<span style='font-size:11.0pt;line-height:105%;font-family:"Calibri",sans-serif;mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:"Times New Roman";mso-ansi-language:DE;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:AR-SA'>
    <span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>         </span>
</span>
```

Note:

- The spaces are located in a separate `<span>` tag with the style-attribute containing a custom key/value pair `mso-spacerun:yes`.
- The HTML is UTF-8 encoded and the char code of the spaces is U+00A0 (no break space).

Comment: Good news! - Interesting solution - I wouldn't have got that - though I still wonder why you want to copy unformatted spaces. But all the best, Tony

Comment: @TonyDuffill: It's the user who might want to do that. :-)